# Detecting if input is a string or an integer

Tags: c++

Please tell me what is wrong in my approach.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string datatype(string x) {
    for (int k = 0; k < strlen(x.c_str());) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            char z = i;
            if (x[k] == z) {
                k++;
            }
            else {
                return "string";
            }
        }
    }
    return "int";
}

int main() {
    string inp;
    cin >> inp;

    cout << datatype(inp);
}
```

Whatever i enter, it always returns "string".
I have seen the other questions posted here but please tell me what is wrong in my approach.

Comment: Why `strlen(x.c_str())` instead of `x.length()` or `x.size()`?

Comment: And in general it seems you could need some extra time reading your text-books. I don't know any character encoding where e.g. `1 == '1'` is true. For ASCII (the most common encoding) it's definitely not true.

Comment: I also recommend that you check out [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) and [`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of). Or perhaps [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Answer (score 4):

The standard library has the [isdigit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) function that tells you if the `char` is a digit.

Here you check that each `char` of your input is a digit, as soon as a character that is not a digit is found `string` is returned, else `int`.

For example `1234` returns `int`, `sdf` returns `string`.

```
string datatype(string str) {
    for (unsigned char c : str) {
        if (!isdigit(c)) {
            return "string";
        }
    }
    return "int";
}
```

Edit: 
This solution also handles leading `-` and `+`. It will return `int` for `-10` and `+10` but returns `string` for `+1+1` or `-10+10`.

```
string datatype(string str) {
    if (str.size() == 1) {
        return isdigit(str[0]) ? "int" : "string";
    }

    bool isInt = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < str.size(); i++) {
        isInt = isInt && isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(str[i]));
        if (!isInt) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isInt) {
        unsigned char c = str[0];
        isInt = isInt && (c == '-' || c == '+' || isdigit(c));
    }

    return isInt ? "int" : "string";
}
```

Comment: One minor nitpick. Better to handle negative numbers as well. `isdigit('-')` returns `false`.

Comment: Please note specifically in the answer that the cast to `unsigned char` is required

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Look at the loop preamble (see? this needs to be explicitly called out for clarity!)

Comment: Then for completeness, you would want to check further if the valid hexadecimal with `isxdigit()` and in addition to the leading `'-'`, a leading `'+'` is also the valid start of a signed value.

Comment: Well, for completeness we could also take into account decimal separators, but that would bring in locale handling too.

Comment: @SilvanoCerza since the question explicitly specifies "integers", decimal points needn't be handled for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Include (cstring) as header since x.c_str is not in iostream and string. Then, 
When you are doing char z=i; here you are not storing the character equivalent of i in z but the ascii value of i. 
Next, You are returning string at the first mismatch between i and x[k]. You should return string if you cannot find a match with any of the possible 10 digits.

You can have a look at the modified code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string datatype(string x) {


    for (int k = 0; k < strlen(x.c_str());k++) {
         int flag=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           // char z = i;
            if ((x[k]-'0') == i || (k==0 && x[k]=='-')) {
                flag=1;
               break;
            }

        }
          if(flag==0)
          return "string";


    }
    return "int";
}

int main() {
    string inp;
    cin >> inp;
   cout << datatype(inp);
}
```

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)